# making an unending javascript function calling for html/css/javascript game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a very simple html(5)/css3 game. I am not using any specific game engine right now. Currently, I am stuck in making the game an unending game play. Lets just say this is my intervals to calling the obstacle.

```
hiddenbox(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    tackle(2000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        //tackle(2000)
        henryAppear(1500,function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                  nextFunction();
                  //it keeps going on and on and on
            },nextSecond)
        },2000)
    })
},3000)
```

})

I was wondering is there a better way to make a simple algorithm to make this sort of function keeps calling the obstacle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `setTimeout`. Use `setInterval`, which continually invokes its callback until you explicitly cancel it.

Comment: after reading your comment, i have a better grasp in it. Thanks a bunch!